# Do other ‘suﬃx­es’ be­sides “‑ere/‑ence/‑ither” ex­ist for com­pos­ing loca­tive and di­rec­tional ‘ad­verbs’ like “here/hither/hence”?

Tags: suffixes, prefixes, deixis, locatives, cranberry-morphemes

Years ago read­ing J R R Tolkien’s *Sil­mar­il­lion*, I learned the de­light­ful
suﬃxes *‑ence* and *‑ither* used in this three­fold set of paired words
with these mean­ings:

1. *hence*: from this nearby place
2. *hither*: toward this nearby place
3. *thence*: from that far place
4. *thither*: toward that far place
5. *whence*: from which place
6. *whither*: toward which place

Recently, as a joke to use such words, I sent a friend an SMS message:

> Later I’ll arrive at your place. I will go hence thither, and return
>   thence hither. Haha.

Now in cre­at­ing this ques­tion, I’ve re­al­ized that there is at least one
more suﬃx that com­bines this way, *‑ere*:

1. here
2. there
3. where

I had­n’t thought about it as a mem­ber of a set of three un­til to­day,
be­cause it’s in ev­ery­day use.  But *‑ence* and *‑ither* have all but
van­ished from ca­sual ev­ery­day speech, and so when some­one uses these it
makes a spo­ken or writ­ten sen­tence more in­ter­est­ing.

So we have the set of three preﬁxes *h‑*, *th-*, and *wh‑* that all
com­bine with an­other set of three suﬃxes *‑ere*, *‑ence*, and *‑ither*
to make nine dif­fer­ent com­bi­na­tions of de­rived words we can use as
loca­tive and di­rec­tional ‘ad­verbs’:

```
           ‑ere    ‑ence    ‑ither
       ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
   h‑  ┃   here    hence    hither
  th-  ┃  there   thence   thither
  wh‑  ┃  where   whence   whither
```

Or grouped the other direction:

```
          h‑      th-      wh‑
       ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
  ‑ere ┃  here    there    where
 ‑ence ┃  hence   thence   whence
‑ither ┃  hither  thither  whither
```

Do other such suﬃxes ex­ist that com­bine with that same three­fold
preﬁx-set of [*h‑*, *th-*, *wh‑*] to make more “*h‑/th‑/wh‑* words” like these?

Do other such preﬁxes ex­ist that com­bine with the same three­fold
suﬃx-set of [*‑ere*, *‑ence*, *‑ither*] to make more
“*‑ere/‑ence/‑ither* words” like these?

Is there some es­say or dis­cus­sion about these and re­lated el­e­ments
some­where out there that ex­plains all this a lit­tle?

---

**Ex­tra thought**: con­sider *‑at* as some sort of suﬃx, as in:

1. *what*
2. *that*
3. While I’m not sure if there’s ever been a word start­ing with *h‑* for
   ‘near­by’, ev­ery­one knows the id­iom *this, that, the other*, so I could
   sug­gest *this* in­stead of ✻*hat* which ap­pears not to ex­ist. Right?

**Another ex­tra thought**: also con­sider *‑en* as some sort of suﬃx, as in:

1. *when*
2. *then*
3. Why is ✻*hen* also miss­ing here like ✻*hat* is miss­ing from the set of
   three *‑at* words just given above?

Comment: I believe this *th-* is from Proto-Indo-European **to-*, a pronominal stem, and *h-* from a Proto-Indo-European pronominal stem *so-*. And I believe *wh-* is from a Proto-Indo-European interrogative stem somewhat like **k(h)ʷ-*. Cf. *he, her, they, then, when, who, which*.

Comment: There are/were hereto, hereunto, thereat.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is mind boggling!!

Comment: Wherefore (art thou Romeo), therefore

Comment: Hereabout, thereabout, whereabouts. There's no end to them!

Comment: All those are interesting too. But I note they're finished with a -ere suffix. Although, perhaps the -ere suffix is a default completion? I had forgot about the term "word stem" until Edwin commented. I don't know if there is a counterpart that describes a default suffix, maybe tip or node. Hereabout, thereabout. Henceforth! Thenceabout?!

Comment: Hereinbefore, thereinbefore, whereinbefore, hereinafter, (etc.) hereinbelow, (etc.) hereinabove, (etc.)

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_pronominal_adverbs

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth also *heretofore*, *theretofore*.  'why' is also *wherefore*, which goes together with *therefore*.  I'm not aware of a *herefore* though...

Comment: Also: hereupon, thereupon, and whereupon.

Comment: Must add two comments, a few years later, submitted as two comments here. One: wow there is a lot of bizarre, almost inane formatting applied to this question in a couple edits made by many-thousands scored users of English SE, albeit much is beneficial.  The second by site moderator adds some formatting to words that does not appear, must be for some screen reader or something.  But 'suffixes' and 'adverbs' in quotes? Anyway... second...

Comment: Second: this is more content in line with the question, and critique of edits.  The latest edit by moderator defeats (reduces at the least) an interpretive capacity of the intended material.  Where I originally had " I could sug­gest this in­stead of Hhat " the Hhat part is replaced by " ✻hat " (my in-quote spaces added for visual clarity).  The interesting part is for Hhat, I have indeed learned, in my travels, of an extant example of this.  From Nederlands, many loanwords and a grapheme (ij) transferred to Engels/English, but not 'het'.  Het is that example.  Hurrah for language learning!

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603965/2085).

Answer (score 3):

What an interesting phenomenon, thanks for asking the question.  In trying to find similar instances, it occurred* to me that there's a relationship between the prefixes of the 5 W's; although not locative or directional, their is a narrative relationship: 'who, what, where, when, why'.

I originally thought of this in Spanish: who = quien, what = que, when = cuando, and (por) que (what for).  The qu and c's are basically equivalent because of their k sound (in Italian the words are also mixed between qu, c and che, a hard k sound, and why is also 'what for'.) 
This may just be coincidence, since the words for where--donde in Spanish, dove in Italian--while obviously related to each other, have no Latin root (that I can find), and the Latin for where, quo, would create 5, rather than 4 q/c/ch/k's.

I'd be interested in any thoughts on the Spanish/Italian equivalents to the English counterparts, and their relationships to each other (not to mention the missing where--well, you'd need a 'where' to find out where the where is, wouldn't you?!

Thanks to all for the interesting posts.

*(I understand the double r in the past tense, but why the double c in occur?)

Comment: Found the Latin origins of donde: (de) unde = (from) whence, and dove: (de) ubi = where!

Comment: That is amazing work! I have read your answer and comment 2-3 times and gone looking now myself based on your thoughts. The do- in spanish and italian appears, at least to me, as a general localization tweak (must be some term for that) on the unde/ubi latin bases. I wonder if there are from (-ence) and toward (-ither) suggestive parts in latin, or other languages.

Answer (score 2):

"-wards" can be locative suffixes that turn a noun into an adverb: viz. homewards, onwards, upwards, downwards, inwards.

Comment: Good find, -ward(s) fits. From your suggestion, I found -ward(s) comes from latin vertere/verto "to turn on, to concern, revolve" etc. From these wikipedia pages: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verto#Latin and http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertere#Italian

Answer (score 1):

"-wise" is another, as in clockwise, counterclockwise (or anticlockwise) and the less-common edgewise, lengthwise, leftwise, and rightwise. Wiktionary has a [long list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-wise#Suffix) under "Derived terms."